# Change the color of text by using applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I am writing some text in to word file i want to change the color of that text any one can help on that one plz.

*I want to print the 'message' from following script in red color.*

**Here is the Script:**

```
set message to "mostly these windows are popup in application"

on ResultCreationFuction(message)

try
    set text_to_save to message as text
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application "Finder"
            set sortedList to sort (get files of folder "SofTestAutomationResult" of desktop) by  modification date
            set FileCount to get count of sortedList
            set theFile to (item FileCount of sortedList) as alias
        end tell

        set file_ref to open for access theFile with write permission           
        write (text_to_save & return) to the file_ref starting at eof
        close access file_ref
        delay 2
        end tell
    end try
end ResultCreationFuction
```

**Some Details:**
The file is word which is all ready present on above location having name "10.012.2014_17_4_20.doc" (the name of .doc file is not fix)

Comment: You need to open the Word document in Word, and then change the text color inside that document. What text are you wanting to change? The whole document? Paragraph 2? Every occurrence of "I should be red."?

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting is the wrong way to do it.

1. To manipulate content like that, including formatted text (not plain
   text), you need to work within, ideally, a well-scriptable app, like
   Pages (or Word, perhaps, but I don't have that on the machine I'm
   writing this from).
2. Don't use System Events if you don't need to. Use the apps with the appropriate AppleEvents/dictionary, etc. If you don't know what I'm talking about, you need to take advantage of the infinite resource known as the web.
3. "Fuction" is just bad form.

I would suggest doing a lot more reading up on how AppleScript works (or scripting in general), but to start you out, here is a script I just wrote in pages which sets the color of a specific word of the open document after putting text in there:

```
tell application "Pages"
    set body text of document 1 to "hello there mister fancy pants"
    set color of word 3 of body text of page 1 of document 1 to {64614, 0, 111}
end tell
```

If you have Pages, try this by starting with a blank page and running this script. Obviously, you could get rid of "word 3 of" in the 2nd line, and the whole body text will be red.

I hope this makes sense and is of help.

**[edit]**

I should mention that even TextEdit is scriptable and can open Word documents. Here's an example using TextEdit:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set text of document 1 to "hello mister fancy pants"
    set color of words 2 thru 3 of text of document 1 to {65535, 0, 0}
end tell
```

There is a little danger of non-Word apps losing formatting of Word files. But it just seems you are attempting something very simple, and I'm not sure if Word is really necessary here.

Comment: He said he wants to use Word.

Comment: Actually, he didn't. He said it is a Word document. And since his attempt completely avoids using any app, I thought it best to start out with a basic concept. Even Text Edit can open Word files and is scriptable. Pages and Text Edit may lose formatting. Perhaps I should've mentioned this.

Comment: Well done, esp with your additions. Just trying to be helpful as it looked like you hadn't noticed they were Word documents. He still probably needs an example using Word.

Comment: Thanks. But I did notice. I just don't see how it is necessary. Also, as I mentioned, I don't have Word on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add color using the write to eof. You should open the document in Word and then insert the line and add the color. Here's a script that should demonstrate how:

```
set text_to_add to "mostly these windows are popup in application"
set theFile to ((path to desktop folder) & "10.012.2014_17_4_20.doc") as string

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set theFile to theFile as string -- assuming theFile is an alias or :: path
    open file theFile

    tell active document
        set endOfDoc to end of content of text object  -- insert the text to end of document
        set theRange to create range start (endOfDoc - 1) end endOfDoc
        insert text text_to_add at theRange

        set myRange to create range start endOfDoc end (endOfDoc + (length of text_to_add))
        set color index of font object of myRange to red

        save
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Hi @jweaks, first of all thanks for looking in to it. i saw your code and it is working but due to this code the MS word file get open in to UI and i don't want that for that only i used the 'write' function, so is there any way to open the ms word file in the back ground.

Comment: tell application "System Events"<br/>
  set msoffice to first process whose name is "Microsoft Word"<br/>
  set visible of msoffice to false<br/>
 end tell  <br/>   if we us this code in above code for first time it will get open in to UI, second time onwards it will open in to background, but for me, it should not open in to UI for first time also.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Word HAS to open the file to work on it, thus bringing it up in the UI. There's no way around that. You will HAVE to open a Word document to insert colored text into it. Only way around that is if the filetype was a markup language like HTML, RTF, etc., but not .doc. However, as you've deduced, you can simply add a hide line. Put it right after the "Open file theFile" line. By the way, you can simplify it as:  tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Word" to set visible to false

Comment: Thanks again @jweaks, a small request from side, can you provide the code for HTML, RTF with respect to above code by using that i will check weather it is compatible or not?

Comment: That's a completely different script. You'll need to accept this answer, and then post a new question on a script for reading and editing HTML.